# Illegal Syntax for Set Operation error

Tags: java, jsf

I have a bean that named FtManagedBean.java

and i have a below jsf:

```
 <h:inputText value="#{ftManagedBean.beginDate}" style="width:95%;"  id="beginDateTxt" />
```

as you see i use my bean with lowering first letter and i get this error:

```
 value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

Why it considers value as a null?

These are the getters and setters:

```
public String getBeginDate() {
    return beginDate;
}

public void setBeginDate(String beginDate) {
    this.beginDate = beginDate;
}
```

Comment: Null isn't "illegal syntax".  You'd have to show what `getBeginDate()` is returning from your bean.

Comment: Can you show Getters and setters for this property in the bean

Comment: please check whether the begindate is null or not...

Comment: i added getters and setters

Comment: You have a `<h:inputText value="">` (yes, just empty string) somewhere in your view, exactly like as the exception message is trying to tell you. Are you sure that you're running the code you think you're running? Clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart.